# Error generating chart: Computation timed out showing in Google Earth Engine

Tags: charts, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to generate a chart of my NDVI values, but I'm getting this error:

*Error generating chart: Computation timed out.*

This is my code..any help-advice would be really helpful!!

It's important to mention that my AOI file contains more than 500 polygons, that have been converted to a multipolygon..I don't know if this is a problem..

Thanks a lot!

```
\\Select the ndvi from an Image Collection
var selectNDVI_2020 = getNDVI_2020.select(['NDVI']); 

\\Plots NDVI
var plot_index= ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(selectNDVI_2020, aoi, ee.Reducer.median(),'NDVI',5000,'system:time_start','system:index')
                .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'Δείκτης NDVI για ' + metavliti +' για το έτος 2020',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}, 
                viewWindow : {max : 1, min : 0},
                colors: ['blue'],
                curveType:'function',
                pointSize: 4
});
print(plot_index,'NDVI_2020');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the AOI is too large for computing.
I change my parameter "scale" from 30 to 300, and find that it was okay.